# How to translate "range from X to Y"?

Tags: translation, grammar

In English I would write something such as

> Low paying jobs range from working at McDonald's to driving a bus.

Or another way to put it

> Low paying jobs include anything from working at McDonald's to driving a bus.

What is the best way to replicate this in Chinese?

(No offense implied to anyone working such jobs.)

Comment: you can use 包括 for *include*

Comment: http://www.iciba.com/range_from..._to_...?renovate=225751

Comment: 在x与（到，和）y之间（的范围），or，范围在x与（到，和）y之间。in your case，use 到，inasmuch you re describing a range not a individual point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on the situation, you might want to say:

> 低收入职业的种类很多，从麦当劳员工到公交车司机不一而足。

You can substitute 不一而足 with 都是 or 应有尽有 or anything that helps to complete the sentence. Examples are abundant in @S.Rhee's link. Or you can somehow reverse it:

> 从麦当劳员工到公交车司机，这些都属于低收入职业。

Funny thing is logically 麦当劳员工 and 公交车司机 don't represent a range. They aren't both end of a continuum, are they? So let's put it another way:

> 低收入职业包括快餐店员工，公交车司机等很多类型。

If you do want to represent a range, you can do:

> 低收入职业包括从快餐店员工到公交车司机的很多类型。

I feel less than comfortable about the last one. I can't tell why, maybe it's because the sentence is too fat and there is no punctuation..

Answer (score 0):

range (means 范围 in Chinese in your case)

from ... to (means two boundaries of a "range")

So, it is "rangeable" for your list items, the two kinds of jobs seem not so good.

Because they are just 2 instance for "low paying jobs", not a clarified bound of this range.

You can set a "paying salary", if you want to use 'range'

Comment: This doesn't answer the question .. user3306356 and S.Rhee's comments both show better suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Low paying jobs range from working at McDonald's to driving a bus.

從在麥當勞打工到當巴士司機這類的低薪工作。

- Low paying jobs => 低薪工作
- working at McDonald's => 在麥當勞打工
- driving a bus => 當巴士司機
- range from ... to ... => 從 ... 到 ...
- ... jobs (which are) range ...,  which are => 這類的

Comment: This is sentence fragmentation -- It's a long noun phrase rather than a sentence.